# when is an 'if' statement code incorrect even after giving an output?

Tags: python, if-statement

am completely new to programming and I am learning through edX now and I came across this code but I do  not really know why the code is termed incorrect even though it gives an output. would have asked on the edx platform but the course finished two years ago, just learning from what is archived. Thanks .

The result is 'i win' and 'tie' it has an output so why is it still incorrect?

```
comp = 'rock'
user = 'rock'

if comp == 'rock':
    print 'I win *_*!'
if user == 'paper':
    print 'You win.'
else:
    print 'Tie.'
```

Really grateful for the replies to my questions but for further clarifications please look at this code here:
    comp == 'rock'
    user == 'rock'

```
if comp == 'paper' and user == 'paper':
    print('tie')
elif comp == 'rock':
    if user == 'scissors':
        print ('I win')
    else:
        print ('You win')
else:
    print ('tie')
```

For user being 'rock', it will print 'you win' from the second test (elif) but the output is said to be incorrect but if user == 'scissors' it will print 'I win' this is said to be correct. My concern is why, what is the difference that makes the if under the second elif correct and the else under the same elif incorrect?

Comment: `if` is not `elif`.

Comment: "I do not really know why the code is termed incorrect even though it gives an output" - we don't call code correct just because it gives an output.

Comment: @user2357112 that's not helpful

Comment: if comp == 'rock'  is true so prints. then the program continues and check if user =='paper', this fails so goes to else and prints you win. If you change if user =='paper' to elif, this will not run if the above if statement is true. Lookup Python Control Flow https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Control_Flow

Comment: @user2357112 I have realised so that is why I want to know the reason why this code is termed incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what happens with the if statements is this.
If your code hits an `if` statement, it will look at the condition and execute it based on the condition, and what happens next, when the first `if` statement didn't get executed is it looks if there are any following `elif`s, or `else`s.
And out of all the `if`, `elif`s, and `else`, only one of them will get executed. Think of it as a big single chunk starting at an `if`, at ending with an `else`.
If there is another `if` statement, your code will look at it again regardless of the previous `if` being executed or not, since your code will think that it is another chunk of conditions.

So in your code, even if your input falls under the first `if` statement, it will still look in to the second `if` and check for the conditions.

I added some comments in your code to make it more intuitive:

```
comp = 'rock'
user = 'rock'

# a code block that needs to be looked at
if comp == 'rock':
    print 'I win *_*!'
# another code block that still has to be checked since it's starting with another if statement
if user == 'paper':
    print 'You win.'
else:
    print 'Tie.'
```

Replacing the second `if` with `elif` will fix the problem.

Answer (score 2):

when you are using an if statement, you are not asking if something is correct, but rather that something is *true or false*. This is known as a boolean operator, and depending on whether it is true of false, leads to either the if statement executing or not executing.

The reason why you are getting the 'tie' to the answer is because you are using two if statements, rather than an elif statement. I've refactored it below for you:

```
comp = 'rock'
user = 'rock'

if comp == 'rock':
    print 'I win *_*!'
elif user == 'paper':
    print 'You win.'
else:
    print 'Tie.'
```

More reading can be found here: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/if-elif-else

Answer (score 0):

Your code will work, with a few syntax corrections:

```
comp = 'rock'
user = 'rock'

if comp == 'rock':
    print('I win *_*!')
elif user == 'paper':
    print('You win.')
else:
    print('Tie.')
```

All I've done here is change the second `if` to `elif`, and put parentheses around the `print` statement output. In Python, 'else if' is written 'elif'. You can have as many `elif` statements as you want.